# Nuxt store mapGetters property is undefined on beforeCreate() hook

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js

I'm experiencing a bug in my nuxt application working with vuex. I'm trying to access a store getter using mapGetters helper but when I access to that property in beforeCreate() hook value is undefined.

*store/user.js*

```
import VuexPersistence from "vuex-persist";

export const plugins = [VuexPersistence];

export const state = () => ({
  user: null,
});


export const getters = {
  isLoggedIn(state) {
    if (state && state.user) {
      console.log("state.user", state.user);
    }
    return state.user !== null && state.user !== {};
  },
};
```

*mycomponent.vue*

```
export default {
  beforeCreate() {
    const isLoggedIn = this.$store.getters["user/isLoggedIn"];

    console.log("computed isLoggedIn", this.isLoggedIn);
    console.log("isLoggedIn", isLoggedIn);
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(["user/isLoggedIn"]),
  },
};
</script>
```

Here is the output result in browser console

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The store is not available in the beforeCreate hook. You could move your code to the mounted() hook, but I would recommend placing it in a middleware for checking if the user is logged in.

middleware/auth-check.js

```
export default function ({ store }) {
  const isLoggedIn = store.getters["user/isLoggedIn"];
  // do something...
}
```

Then add to your page:

```
export default {
  ...
  middleware: 'auth-check'
  ...
}
```

Comment: Could you please give me more information about the parameter that is passed to auth-check.js? I would like to handle a $router.push redirect

Comment: Yep, you can pull redirect from the context and use it. Glad you worked it out.